# How to prepend a Hashtag to an attribute of a data-target when adding a new target .Using pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to this, so thank you for you help.
From my Sql  database result rows  I use a php variable to add the row id to a buttons data-target.  The button opens my modal in a bootstrap card.  The row id gives it a unique number. It works well below.

```
<a class="my-btn" data-toggle="modal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#modal<?php echo $rowid;?>" >MyButton</a>
```

**Problem:**
I have moved to Dynamic creation of records. The data now comes in a json array via a GET. So  to process the data I use change JS Attribute

```
$('.card').find('.my-btn').attr('data-target',record.rowid);
```

The above applies it, but the button does not work because I Have not prepended the hash tag.  is there a way to add the hash like below example.

```
$('.card').find('.my-btn').attr('data-target',#record.rowid);
```

My full script is below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
       url: 'scripts/sql.php',
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: function(result){
       data =(result);


   $.each(data, function( i, record ) {
   if(i == 0) {

     $('.card').find('.firstname').text(record.firstname);
     $('.card').find('.surname').text(record.surname);
     $('.card').find('.my-btn').attr('data-target',record.recordid);
     
   
   } else {
   
     var recordDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone();
     recordDetailCloned.find('.firstname').text(record.firstname);
     recordDetailCloned.find('.surname').text(record.surname);
     recordDetailCloned.find('.my-btn').attr('data-target',record.recordid);
  

      $('.card-container').append(recordDetailCloned);
      
     

   }
     
 });
 
 }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: You don't mean just `'#' + record.recordid` do you?

Comment: Yes Acidc9  looks like what I want, let me test it

Comment: I tried  '#' + record.firstname becuase  i can see firstname and check if it is added. it did not work.  It made the firstname diappear.  Thanks  for trying

Comment: Acidc9 it Works what you said  '#' + record.recordid  WORKS!   Sorry i have a coding error on my testing code.  Please put it as your anser so I can give you a tick!  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just be looking to prefix your variable with a string.

This can be done one of two ways:

```
`#${record.recordid}`
```

or

```
'#' + record.recordid
```